# Javascript rails auto complete search drop down click event

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, autocomplete

I have a [twitter typeahead auto complete search box](http://jsfiddle.net/freit5/NmxDw/1/) working and my next step is to be able to click or hit enter on a result and be taken to the item's page.

Any ideas or working examples I can look at? I've looked at options like swiftype.com but would rather do it the hard way first.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('input.typeahead').typeahead({
name: 'names',
prefetch: '../sub_categories/names',
remote: '../sub_categories/names?q=%QUERY',
minLength: 2,
limit: 10,
select: function(event, ui){
  start_search=false;
  $('search_item_id').value = ui.item.id;
  $('search_item_type').value = ui.item.klass;
  $('search_form').submit();
  }
 });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery autocomplete. http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/
And for redirecting it to some page, you can always capture events (like enter or click) and take appropriate action.